# How to use a string from python code in kv fille?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I am making an object tracking app for school and need to use the string value from my username and use it in my kv file as a title for my MDtoolbar.

I want to use the username from def verify in the last if.
And sent them to my Toolbar in my mainscreen

Can somebody help me with this problem?

```
class GipApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = 'Blue'
        screen = Builder.load_string(screen_helper)
        self.username = "unknown"
        return screen


    def verify(self, username, password):
        if username != "" and password != "":
            for row in MySqlNames:
                if row[0].strip() == username:
                    sql = "SELECT Password from ID191774_6itn1project7.Users where Username = %s "
                    mycursor.execute(sql, (username))
                    TestPassword = mycursor.fetchall()
                    for row3 in TestPassword:
                        if row3[0].strip() == password:
                            dialog = MDDialog(title="Login successful")
                            dialog.open()
                            self.username = username
                            I WANT THIS USERNAME TO USE IN THE KV FILLE
                            GipApp.get_running_app().root.current = 'main'


                        if row3[0] != password:
                            dialog = MDDialog(title="Passwords is not correct.")
                            dialog.open()

        else:
            dialog = MDDialog(title="Fill in the empty text boxes")
            dialog.open()
```

```
<MainScreen>:
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: 'mountains.jpg'
    name: 'main'
    NavigationLayout:
        ScreenManager:
            Screen:    
                orientation: 'vertical'
                MDToolbar:
                    title: I WANT THE USERNAME HERE
                    left_action_items:[["menu",lambda x: nav_drawer.toggle_nav_drawer()]]
                    elevation :12
                    pos_hint:{"center_x": .5, "center_y": .95}
                Widget:
                MDRoundFlatButton:
                    text: 'Start Object identify here'
                    text_color:(1, 1, 1, 1)
                    size: 110, 110
                    on_release: app.Yolo()
                    pos_hint:{"center_x": .5, "center_y": 0.5}
                MDLabel:
                    text:"Press esc to stop."
                    halign:'center'
                    theme_text_color:'Custom'
                    text_color:(1, 1, 1, 1)
                    font_style:'Subtitle1'
                    pos_hint:{"center_x": .5, "center_y": 0.35}
                    ter_y": 0.35}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a variable in the class like `self.username` and in your kv file `title: app.username`